# Alternative to the Facebook Comment Box Plugin?

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, sdk

I'm about to embed Facebook Comments on a website but I feel very limited in the way of styling the iFrame solution. The only options with the Comment Box Plugin is colorscheme="light/dark".

Note: The css parameter  seems to be deprecated so that's unfortunately not a solution.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

Is it possible to make another custom solution by using the API (JSON, Javascript, PHP) or something?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add a style attribute to my <fb:comments> tag

Comment: That's another thing. What I'm after is styling what's inside the iFrame.